# How to use/Implement OAuth2 with Owin in ASp.net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Hello I am very beginner in whole web development ,  I got a task to make an API and for the good or bad of it I chose Asp.Core to do it .

The api connects a mobile client with a CRM system and there is an AD system (Not azure nor windows AD) it is called NetIQ. Any request to the api has to be from a user who is authenticated by Net IQ before then the API issues a token to the client.

Anyway I would like to have kind of authentication mechanism, and I have been told that OWIN can handle OAUTh2 stuff .

I have the exact code that I need , but it is with MVC 5.

Can someone help me with migrating this thing to MVC core ?

I searched for long time and could not find what I want . Maybe because i am still a bigenner in the web stuff area .

The code that I want to migrate is

***Startup.cs***

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

***Startup.Auth.cs***

```
 public partial class Startup
    {
        public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

        public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
            PublicClientId = "self";
            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
            };
            // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
        }
    }
```

***ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs***

```
public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private static string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
    private static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAD.Tenant"];
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAD.ClientId"];
    private static string authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);
    private static AuthenticationContext authContext = null;


    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new TokenCache());
        var creds = new UserPasswordCredential(context.UserName, context.Password);
        AuthenticationResult result;
        try
        {
            result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(clientId, clientId, creds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));

        context.Validated(identity);

    }
}
```

So have anyone a sample how would I do that in ASP core ? because the whole startup thing is making me confused to be honest .

Comment: Unfortionately none of these components work with ASP.NET Core. There are several alternatives listed here: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/83